# Limit to only relevant results - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, SUM(Relevance) as SearchRelevance 
FROM( 
SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, 1 as Relevance FROM cars 
WHERE cat LIKE '%$keyword%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, 1 as Relevance FROM cars 
WHERE cat2 LIKE '%$keyword2%') 
AS t GROUP BY rideid ORDER BY SUM(Relevance) DESC ";
```

Hi all, I got this awesome query with the help of other members, which works very well in sorting my results based on a relevance system.  So that when both of my search criteria are filled those results are ordered first.

The problem is that the results which don't match both criteria (only match 1 criteria) obviously show up in the results, but in a lower order.  I want to actually trash those results, is there a way to refine this query so that the only results that come back are the ones that fill both criteria?

Changing the LIKE to = is not an option because the result fields are textareas so mysql needs to search inside the textareas for the keyword.

Thank you

Comment: Do those `$keyword` and `$keyword2` values come from user input?  Make sure you're not introducing an SQL injection vulnerability with this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add `HAVING SUM(Relevance) = 2` to the outer `SELECT`, just after the `GROUP BY rideid`, since `Relevance` is a count of how many criteria matched.  (If you add more criteria later, you'll need to replace the 2 with a larger number to match.)

However, you could also write the whole query in a much simpler way:  get rid of the sub-select and `UNION ALL`, and just do `WHERE cat LIKE '%$keyword%' AND cat2 LIKE '%$keyword2%'`.  The whole point of the sub-select and `UNION` was to make it possible to get results that match only one or the other.

Comment: Adding HAVING SUM doesn't work for me unfortunatly, just a standard 1064 mysql error.  I will try rewriting as you suggested, but I would like to keep the flexibility of sometimes having the less relevant results (depending on what the user checks on a form)

Comment: Sorry you were right about the placement of the HAVING, I made a mistake earlier, this works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, SUM(Relevance) as SearchRelevance 
      FROM( 
        SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, 2 as Relevance FROM cars 
          WHERE cat LIKE '%$keyword%' AND cat2 LIKE '%$keyword2%') 
        AS t GROUP BY rideid ORDER BY SUM(Relevance) DESC
```

Comment: +1 for removing the union, but you could probably also get rid of the outer select and group by clauses as well. However It also might not work if the OP is looking to do relavence >2

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or you will always getting SUM(Relevance)=2 for records matching both conditions?

Comment: Yes you will get that =2 for both matches, but mysql will still return the other results, just ordered lower.

Comment: If I'm right and you want to calculate the relevance by times the keyword is found in the text, you should see into [example how to get substring count inside the text](http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, SUM(Relevance) SearchRelevance
FROM( 
    SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, 1 as Relevance FROM cars 
    WHERE cat LIKE '%$keyword%' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rideid, year, model, rating, 1 as Relevance FROM cars 
    WHERE cat2 LIKE '%$keyword2%'
) AS t 
HAVING SearchRelevance > 1
GROUP BY rideid 
ORDER BY SearchRelevance DESC
```

Comment: This does not work, with error code: Unknown column 'SearchRelevance' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thanks! I used this in combination with Wyzard's suggestion and it works!