# PHP PDO Full text, limit by relevance score

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In similarity to [Limit to only relevant results - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411499/limit-to-only-relevant-results-mysql) I need to limit the returned results by their score e.g. `3`.

This is my query but it does not work atm:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT 
                        id
                        , MATCH (title,edition) AGAINST (:query) AS score
                        , 3 as score 
                      FROM hb_articles 
                      WHERE MATCH(title,edition) AGAINST(:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                      order by score desc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the alias `score` to a constant `3`.

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT  
  id 
  , MATCH (title,edition) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM hb_articles  
WHERE MATCH(title,edition) AGAINST(:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
HAVING score <= 3   //or >= 3 I always forget how match against works.
ORDER BY score DESC');
```